# Coprime integers

Tags: c#, cryptography

I'm trying to create an Coprime integers for my afinne code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "";
            string openMessage = "";
            openMessage = openMessage.ToUpper();
            string cryptedMessage = "";
            int a;
            int b;
            int m;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the modular size of the alphabet:");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            m = int.Parse(input);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter first value for encrypting the message:");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            a = int.Parse(input);
            while(a!=0 && m !=0)
            {
                if (a > m)
                {
                    a %= m;
                } else
                {
                    m %= a;
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Enter second value for encrypting the message:");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            b = int.Parse(input);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the message you want to encrypt:");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            openMessage = input.ToUpper();

            foreach (char letter in openMessage)
            {
                int letterNumber = (int)letter;
                letterNumber = (a * (letterNumber - 65) + b) % m; //Afinne Cipher math
                letterNumber = letterNumber + 65;
                char encryptedLetter = (char)letterNumber;
                cryptedMessage = cryptedMessage + encryptedLetter;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(cryptedMessage);

        }
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to do that?

I want to compare with `int m` and `int a`. I looked up to the Google and found [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Coprime.aspx) but looks kinda difficult to implement to my code.

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm for GCDs is very easy to implement. Why do you think it hard?

Comment: Because im still beginner in coding

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor

Comment: The code for it is somewhat similar to the while loop that you already have, so I don't think that it involves anything that you don't already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) for determination of the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of two nonnegative integers can be implemented in C# as follows.

```
public int Gcd(int m, int n)
{
    var tmp = 0;
    if (m < n)
    {
        tmp = m;
        m = n;
        n = tmp;
    }
    while (n != 0)
    {
        tmp = m % n;
        m = n;
        n = tmp;
    }
    return m;
}
```

Based on this implementation, a fraction `m/n` can be reduced with the following function.

```
public void Reduce(ref int m, ref int n)
{
    var Gcd = Gcd(m, n);
    m /= Gcd;
    n /= Gcd;
}
```

Comment: I found also BigInteger.ModPow();. Is better for euclidean algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Codor's solution is good, if you wanted something meant for readability based straight off of Euclidean

```
public bool IsCoprime(int a, int b)
{
 int ld, ldRem;
 
 while (b > 0)
 {
   ld = a / b;
   ldRem = a % b;
   a = b;
   b = ldRem;
 }
 if (a == 1) return true;
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).